# How to order by this query?

Tags: php, sql, sql-order-by

I have table of likes/dislikes on game: `id`, `game_id`, `type`(like/dislike), `time`

Table example: [Image Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ye7aL.png)

This code gives me the last week games the had likes, order by their likes count:

```
$limit = 10;
$time = _time() - 60*60*24*7;
$games_id = array();
$games_id_query = $this->db->execQuery("SELECT `game_id`, count(*) as `likes_count` FROM `likes` WHERE `type` = 'like' AND `time` > '{$time}' group by `game_id` order by `likes_count` DESC LIMIT {$limit}");
$games_id_num = $games_id_query->num_rows;
if($games_id_num > 0) {
    while($row = $games_id_query->fetch_object()) {
        unset($row->likes_count);
        $games_id[] = (array) $row;
    }
}
```

I need addition to this code. I want one more order by, and it will be the dislikes count of this game_id, ASC.

How should I do this? with SQL only... thanks very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want something like this:

```
SELECT `game_id`,
    SUM(IF(`type` = 'like', 1, 0)) AS likes_count,
    SUM(IF(`type` = 'dislike', 1, 0)) AS dislikes_count
FROM `likes`
WHERE `time` > '{$time}'
GROUP BY `game_id`
ORDER BY `likes_count` DESC, `dislikes_count` ASC
LIMIT {$limit}
```

That being said, please look into using prepared statements and parameterized queries instead of directly embedding your PHP variables in your SQL.

See this question for more information: [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php/60496)

Answer (score -1):

Change from DESC to ASC, is that what you want?

```
  SELECT game_id, count(*) as likes_count
    FROM likes
   WHERE type = 'like'
     AND time > '{$time}'
   group by game_id
   order by likes_count ASC LIMIT {$limit}
```